# Java - One parseInt shows error, the other one doesn't

Tags: java, arraylist, parseint

I've been doing my homework, but I ran into a problem. My code scans some information about books (author, title etc..) from a txt file then prints it. First I tried to print the author, title, ISBN code, the number of the pages, then the price of the books which is 15*number of pages. It works so far, however I wanted to add a number for each book, so it goes like a list. But when I modified the code to add those numbers, the code didn't want to scan them. it says

> int cannot be converted to String

I tried to scan the numbers as Strings out of curiosity, but then the error message said that

> String cannot be converted to int

My Book class:

```
    public class Book {
    private int number;
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String code;
    private int pages;
    private static int multiplier = 15;

    public Book(String author, String title, String code, int pages, int number) {
        this.number = number;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.code = code;
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return author + " - " + title + ", ISBN:" + code + ", " + pages + " pages, Price: " + price() + "Ft";
    }

    public int price() {
        return multiplier * pages;
    }

    public static int getMultiplier() {
        return multiplier;
    }

    public static void setMultiplier(int multiplier) {
        Book.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }


    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

}
```

And my "Controller" class:

```
public class Controller {

void start() {
    scanning();
    printing("Avilable books: ");        


}

private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();


private void scanning() {

    try {
        Scanner fajlScanner = new Scanner(new File("books.txt"));
        String row;
        String data[];
        while (fajlScanner.hasNextLine()) {

            row = fajlScanner.nextLine();
            data = row.split(";");
            //1;J.K. Rowling;Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone;1782637594826;342
            //this line below gives the error for the data[0]
            books.add(new Book(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), data[1], data[2], data[3], Integer.parseInt(data[4])));

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void printing(String title) {
    System.out.println(title);
    for (Book book : books) {
        System.out.println(book);

    }
}
}
```

The content of my txt:

```
1;J.K. Rowling;Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone;1782637594826;342
2;J.R.R. Tolkien;The Fellowship of the Ring;1827493762573;431
3;Stephen King;Needful Things;8274653821647;411
4;Eric Knight;Lassie Come-Home;7263845618293;138
5;Molnár Ferenc;A pál utcai fiúk;9283746192846;194
6;Winston Groom;Forrest Gump;0385231342;228
7;Antoine de Saint-Exupéry;The Little Prince;8362748172649;69
8;Stephen King;Cujo;2918467382914;362
```

I can scan the pages good, but it has some problem with the "number".

Comment: How to help without books.txt? Why not print out the contents of each array **before** parsing to test the variables for yourself? Or use a debugger.

Comment: You seem to be trying to pass the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: Consider putting each parsing on a line of its own -- to make debugging easier. Print out each String before it's parsing. Check that the lines don't need to be `trim()`'ed before parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input is: 1;J.K. Rowling;Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone;1782637594826;342

your constructor is:

```
public Book(String author, String title, String code, int pages, int number){
/*.
.
.*/
}
```

first character of input is "1" which is an integer but in your constructor the first parameter is a `String`. that's why the error showed up. "1" must be at the end of the input according to the constructor.

for set a number for each book, use a additional `static` variable, initialize it to 1, every time you wanna add a book, set the current value of the static variable for the book's number, then `++` it.

```
public class Book {

private static int counter=1;

private int number;
private String author;
private String title;
private String code;
private int pages;
private static int multiplier = 15;

public Book(String author, String title, String code, int pages, int number) {
    this.number = counter;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.code = code;
    this.pages = pages;
    counter++;
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: Re-ordering the constructor solved the problem, thank you!
However, when I want to run the code, I get an error message saying:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1""
Do you what can cause this?

Comment: @DewSee this error showed up when you're trying to set a non-integer value to an integer variable. check your code carefully, you'll find it.

Comment: Yes, as I saw the problem is still with the `Integer.parseInt(data[0])`. When I scan it only as a string it works, but it would be much more elegant and efficient to use them as integers. That's why I used parseInt, but something else is the problem, I just can't figure it out. Could you give me some more clue?

Comment: @DewSee look at the the error message: `For input string: "1"" `. it is saying that you are trying to store `1"` in an integer variable. check the input, it seems that the problem is in the input. i should have whole of your code to figure out where exactly is the problem.

Comment: Actually the problem was, that the txt file had an invisible dot before the "1", that's why it wasn't able to scan it. As far as I know, it's because it's kind of a mark for the UTF-8 coding. But anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are giving the right parameters in the right order to your Book-constructor.

The constructor:

```
public Book(String author, String title, String code, int pages, int number)
```

Your object creation:

```
new Book(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), data[1], data[2], data[3], Integer.parseInt(data[4]))
```

Can you spot the error?

Comment: I did, thank you. It seems fine now, however, when I want to run it, I get an error saying this:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1""

Comment: Try specifying the correct charset for the Scanner.
`Scanner fajlScanner = new Scanner(new File("books.txt"), "UTF-8");`
Replace UTF-8 with the encoding used on the books.txt.